# Rails strong params don't allow to pass data

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, authentication, strong-parameters

I am trying to create an authentication component on with React on the FE and Rails BE.

I'm not sure what's the issue here, when i send a request to the API to create the user. the password is not permitted and the application breaks.

My Signup action on the FE:

```
export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk('user/signupUser', 
    async(userData, thunkAPI) => {
        console.log('userData',userData)
        let url = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
        let apiObject = {
            method:'POST',
            headers: {
                accept: "application/json",
                "content-type":"application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                user_name: userData.name,
                email: userData.email,
                password: userData.password,
                password_confirmation: userData.password_confirmation
            })
        }
        fetch(url, apiObject)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    }

)
```

My User Model on the BE:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password

    validates :user_name, presence: true
    validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true

    # has_many :reports dependent: :destroy
    # has_many :properties dependent: :destroy
end
```

user/controller on the BE:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


    def index
        users = User.all
        render json: users
    end

    def create
        user = User.new(user_params)
         binding.pry
        if user.save && user.authenticate(user_params[:password])
            binding.pry
            token = encode_token({user_id: user.id})
            render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(user).serializable_hash, token: token}, status: :created
        else
            render json: {error: user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end

    end

    private 

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:user_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

I used pry to try to understand so here's the flow:
UI- signup
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zvEc.png)

and this is the breakpoint when the params can't pass the passwords.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODczT.png)

Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

The controller expects the payload in the following structure as
defined by: `params.require(:user).permit(:user_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)`

```
{
   user: 
     {
        username: <value>,
        email: <value>,
        password: <value>,
        password_confirmation: <value>
     }
}
```

In your SignUp action, pass the payload accordingly:

```
export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk('user/signupUser', 
    async(userData, thunkAPI) => {
        console.log('userData',userData)
        let url = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
        let apiObject = {
            method:'POST',
            headers: {
                accept: "application/json",
                "content-type":"application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                user: {
                    user_name: userData.name,
                    email: userData.email,
                    password: userData.password,
                    password_confirmation: userData.password_confirmation
                }
            })
        }
        fetch(url, apiObject)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    }
)
```

For further reading, refer [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.2.3/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html).